# Customize font style for multi-line text field

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

Is there a way to customise the font-style used by a multi-line text field in the Content Editor interface? Note - I don't care about styling for the front-end as this is handled by our regular CSS.

Bonus points if there is a way of using the source property of the template field to "switch this on" just for certain templates/fields.

Comment: Customize for display in the Content Editor, or the rendered output on your frontend site?

Comment: Customised for the content editor. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Multi-Line Text` field does not read or use the `Source` field in any way, unlike some of the other fields. The only way to set additional custom CSS classes using this type of field is to [create a custom field](https://www.sitecore.net/company/blog/474/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field-4246).

If you just want to style all Multi-Line Text fields then overriding the style is the best option, but I would suggest you create a custom processor to [inject the resources into the Content Editor](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-custom-javascript-and-stylesheets-in-the-content-editor/), which keeps it clean for future upgrades:

```cs
public class InjectResources
{
    public List<string> Styles { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Scripts { get; private set; }

    public InjectResources()
    {
        this.Styles = new List<string>();
        this.Scripts= new List<string>();
    }

    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.IsEvent || HttpContext.Current == null || (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page) == null)
            return;

        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        foreach (var style in Styles)
        {
            page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl($"<link href=\"{style}\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"));
        }

        foreach (var script in Scripts)
        {
            page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl($"<script src=\"{script}\"></script>"));
        }
    }
}
```

And patch this in, specifying your override scripts:

```xml
<pipelines>
  <renderContentEditor>
    <processor patch:before="*[1]" type="MyProject.Pipelines.InjectResources, MyProject.Custom">
      <styles hint="list">
        <style>/path/to/custom.css</style>
      </styles>
      <scripts hint="list">
        <script>/path/to/custom.js</script>
      </scripts>
    </processor>
  </renderContentEditor>
</pipelines>
```

You can use a CSS file like @SitecoreClimber has recommended:

```css
.scContentControlMemo
{
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

If you still want to control the styling per field but do not want to create a custom field, then you could use a bit of JavaScript trickey along with an existing field property such as the `Short Description` field. Set the field to something unique like **"[Code]"** (this also means that the field alt title in EE does not look off since it is still relevant).

[image: Short Description field]

Inject in a JS file and observe the `sc:contenteditorupdated` event which means [your code will fire when a different item is selected in the Content Editor](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/hiding-content-editor-fields-depending-on-selected-values/):

```js
document.observe("sc:contenteditorupdated", function(event) {
    $sc(".scContentControlMemo").each(function (index, item) {
        var $fieldContainer = $sc(this).parent();
        if ($fieldContainer.prev().immediateText().endsWith("[Code]:")) {
            $fieldContainer.addClass("code");
        };
    });
});

$sc.fn.immediateText = function() {
    return this.contents().not(this.children()).text();
};
```

The above will add a **code** class to the parent `div` of the Multi-Line Text field. Update the CSS from earlier to take this into account:

```css
.code .scContentControlMemo
{
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

This ensures that any default fields, such as those defined in Standard Values, do not have the custom styling applied.

[image: Updated field styles]

Answer (score 4):

You need to include your custom css into file :

\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Default.aspx

You need to add :

```
<link href="yourrelativepathtocustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Your css file it will include:

```
 **.scContentControlMemo
   {
      font-size:50px; 
      font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;

   }**
```

These class used by css is added in the constructor of Multiline field (memo field)

```
// Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Memo
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Memo" /> class.
/// </summary>
public Memo()
{
    this.Class = "scContentControlMemo";
    base.Wrap = "soft";
    base.Activation = true;
}
```

Result of these changes on below picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply and code-free on a per-field basis by setting the `Style` field of the item for that template's field you want to change:

[image: Editing the field item's style field]

And this will update the appearance of that particular field when editing an item:

[image: The resulting field]

For the curious - in the case of a multi-line text-field, the value you provided in the style field will be injected in as style attribute on the `textarea` by the Content Editor, as shown here:

[image: The injected style attribute]